# get posts by meta_key from inside key of post meta

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

How can i get posts sorted out by meta_key from inner key array of post meta values, for more details please look at my code:

```
// Example output of each post_meta, key is views

array(
    'all' => '334',
    'new' = '28',
    'old' => '280'
)

// wp_query with meta_query not working with above meta_key 

$popular = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'             => 'songs',
    'showposts'             => '20',
    'order'                 => 'DSC',
    'meta_key'              => 'views', // i want something like this views['all']
    'orderby'               => 'meta_value_num'
) );
```

Comment: I am about 99% sure that you can't do this with `WP_Query` because the [data is serialized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817950/what-is-data-serialization) in the database ( automagically ). The solution would be to split them into their own post meta key value pairs than an array.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee is correct. `WP_Query` won't do this without a lot of help from filters but I'd sort in PHP if it were me. The complexity of the query you'd need is pretty high and I doubt the query would be efficient.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee, s_ha_dum Thanks for ur comment, I feared from this, Is there any way to get all posts then with one foreach do sorting posts by that array first key ?! It is possible ?!

Comment: It's possible but the overhead wouldn't be worth it. You're talking about 1 possibly **huge** database query to get all posts, 1 loop through the possibly **huge** amount of posts to make another database query to get the `post_meta` array and put it into a separate possibly **huge** related array, then another loop to actually sort that possibly **huge** amount of data on one specific key. I think in the long run you're better off spending the time now to make your queries and postmeta easier in the future for both sanity and speeds sake.

Comment: Never use serialized data if later you need to query individual data. That is why the database design decisions are so important early at the development stage. Better just save them as `view_new`, `view_old` and `view_all`. If you have existing data in the database. I will advice you to write code which (run once) go through each post and split the data into three individual meta.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, So, is better if i split meta_box keys to three different keys. Anyway wordpress developers should think about adding this feature to meta_query :)

Comment: This is not something you can add to `meta_query`. It is a limit at the database level. The database can't reliably manage serialized data, which is a PHP construct, not a MySQL one. It is just bad, bad, bad data design to shove multiple pieces of different information into the same key. It is a bit like making trailmix out of your information and expecting to be able to easily un-trailmix later.